# CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE keeps changing

Tags: kernel, size, opencl

I am trying to normalize all vectors in a 100x2025 matrix (100 vectors). I process each vector as a work group in local memory. My max work group size is 512 so I originally set global size to {100, 2048} and local size to {1,512} (I process 4 elements per work item and I pad the vectors with zeros in the kernel to make it a power of 2.)

After some trouble I realized that while my max work group size for device is 512, my KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE was 256.

So now I process 8 elements per work item with a 256 work groups...

Well I just made a very subtle change to my kernel (changed a "get_local_size(0)" call to "get_local_size(1)") and now my KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE is 224 and I get invalid work group size??

This is very frustrating and I do not understand what dictates the change. My global work size isn't even divisible by 224.

Comment: If you change your code, the compiled code will also change, and may lead to a change in the maximum size. That is something that effectively will happen on low end devices. So it is considered a bad practice to FIX a kernel only to a given size. You should depend on the `get_local_size()` values.

Answer (score 0):

As you can already guess by the name, `KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` is the maximum work group size for a specific kernel. This number depends on the kernel source code, the specifics of the OpenCL implementation you use, the device hardware, and is influenced by the number of registers and local memory used in your kernel. It will often be lower than `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` which is the theoretical maximum work group size for a compute device.

I usually set the local workgroup size in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` to `NULL` to let the implementation decide on a good value. You should always introspect the workgroup size with `get_local_size()` in your kernel code and not rely on any specific workgroup size.